# How to implement single session per user in passportjs in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport,passport-local in nodejs to authenticate user.By default passport allow multiple session per user.But I want to implement single session per user.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know session will be alive forever until the user logs out. The logic can be used like you can save a login status `logged_in` in DB and check every time when the user try to login. If you get the status `logged_in` as `true` then you can deny that user to login.